# show a button on getting json response equal to a string like @"unapproved"

Tags: ios, json

Here I am fetching some clips from API. And i want to display a button when the status of clip is unapproved so in json response currently i am showing "0" for "unapproved". so now want to display a button when
staus is "0". i got below code from stack only and is working fine upto [park enumerateObjectUsingBlock ..] i am getting response as state equal to "1" and of some clips "0". but my code doesn't work after NSSring *title it shows title as nil so tell me how to get the value in *title

```
 // log debugger response -- park=(__NSArrayM) *    @"3 objects"    
                         [0]    (MyVideos *)  
 //  _clip_name=(NSTaggedPointerString) *   @"Kotak1"       
 // _state=(NSTaggedPointerString) *    @"1"    
 // _clip_image_path=(__NSCFString *)@"1EKNA1464617788.jpg" 

 // status = (NSString *)nil     

 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"task=webapi.getJClips"];

 park = [jsonLoader videosFromJSONFile:url];

[park enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {

 // if i add a breakpoint at above line and on this line it give me response state = "1" but on below line it crashes

 //here it crashes on below line in debugger it shows title nil

  NSString *title = object[@"state"];

  }

  // here below is code for showing hidden button after getting response "0" 

if ([title isEqual:@"0"]) {

        //If so, get the correct button from the enumerate idk and set hidden NO and text = title
  //      UIButton *button = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:idx];
   //     button.hidden = NO;
    //    button.text = title;
    }
```

Comment: You need to at least show the JSON or a log of the `park`

Comment: in the code section at starting that is my json response _clip name and _state   @wain

Answer (score 1):

1. You are declaring NSString *title within a block, so this not going to work outside of the block.
2. if([title isEqual:@"0"]) is comparing object pointers and should be if([title isEqualToString:@"0"]), to compare an NSString to another NSString
3. Since the block is run independently, your title will not be set before the "if([title..." line is executed
4. UI operations must be run on the main thread

So, after all of that, a better approach would be:

```
[park enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id object, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    if([object[@"state"] isEqualToString:@"0"]) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            UIButton *button = [buttonArray objectAtIndex:idx];
            button.hidden = NO;
            button.text = title;

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't know that this isn't run on the main thread, and the enumeration isn't pushed to a background thread, but other than that +1

Comment: The code is not working... app crashes giving error --- [MyVideos objectForKeyedSubscript:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance it crashes at if([object[@"state"] isEqualToString:@"0"])   line   @Dominic

Comment: help me plz...@ Dominic

Comment: You may have to cast the object[@"state"] result to an NSString, without seeing your data it's difficult to know for sure what the app is expecting.  A 'quick and dirty' way to overcome the problem is: NSString *stateString = object[@"state"];     if([stateString isEqualToString:@"0"])

Comment: @Dominic: `isEqual:` doesn't perform pointer comparison; it works about as well as `isEqualToString:` (i.e. doesn't take into account things like Unicode normalisation forms, but otherwise works correctly).

Comment: Sorry, 'pointer' should be 'object'... works about as well is an interesting point, https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/isequal-vs-isequaltostring/ has a nice discussion on the topic. For me, when I'm comparing strings, I think isEqualToString is more explicit and better practice but I guess we all have personal preferences.