# How to logout without setting "userID" nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, logout

With the following code I am able to logout successfully and show the login screen when the application is opened again.

I have a user profile page where I fetch all the data of a particular user. However, a problem occurs after logging in. I get all the user's data. Then when I minimise the application and open it again, all the data in my profile page is lost. I think this is because I am setting the user id to `nil` with `setObject` method.

Does anyone have any idea about how to make this work?

```
- (IBAction)logoutButtonTapped:(id)sender {

   UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] 
       initWithTitle:@"Confirmation" 
       message:@"Do you want to Logout?"
       delegate:self
       cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
       otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

   [alert show];


    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

   [prefs setObject:nil forKey:@"userID"];

   [prefs synchronize];

}
```

Below is the code I am using to LOGOUT:

```
  -(void)nextScreen: (NSTimer *) timer
 {
      NSLog(@"TEST");
      NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
     UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
     MenuScreenViewController *viewcontroller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"loginScreenViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:viewcontroller animated:YES];
  }


   -(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:  (NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
      NSTimer* timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2
                                                  target:self
                                                  selector:@selector(nextScreen:)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:NO];

     [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
     [timer fire];


   if (buttonIndex != 0)  // 0 == the cancel button
  {
    //home button press programmatically
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    [app performSelector:@selector(suspend)];

    //wait 2 seconds while app is going background
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.0];

    //exit app when app is in background
     NSLog(@"TIMER CALLED");
     exit(0);
}else{

     }
```

Comment: Do any one have idea about this what should i use in else method to be on same view or dismiss the alert view

Answer (score 0):

you can take one `bool` variable which is stored login status. If successfully logged in then store status to `yes` to `NSUserdefaults`. And store `NO` when use click `logout`. 
So, you can check at a `time of app launching` that if status is true then `rootviewcontroller` is `homescreen` else `logingscreeen`

Don't manipulate `userId` so you can use it. Use this bool status.

Second thing If you showing alertview for confirming on logout button click then don't manipulate `NSUserdefaults` in that action method. Because if user will press `cancel` then also your `user default` will be change and consider user as `logout`.

So, you should use `alertview delegate` methods to handle click on `alertview`. You should manipulate `user defaults` from `ok` button's click of `alertview` which can be achieved by delegate methods.

Hope this will help :)

Comment: thanks for answering but can you explain this with code i am not getting it exactly how to do that @Lion

Answer (score 0):

When you call `[alert show]`, it seems like you're assuming that it stops executing your method there and only continues if the user taps *OK*.  It doesn't work that way.  What happens is that you're showing the alert view, your method continues, then sets your `userID` to `nil` *immediately*, before you tap any button.  You then tap on a button in the alert view, and the information about what you tapped is thrown away.

If you want to log somebody out only if they tap *OK*, then you need to implement the `UIAlertViewDelegate` protocol, and set your `userID` to `nil` in the delegate method if the right button is tapped.

Note that `UIAlertView` is deprecated, and you should be using `UIAlertController` in new code.

Comment: i have used delegate method that code is not posted here

Comment: But the code you use to log out *is* posted here, and it's in the wrong place.  You need to put it in the delegate method.

Comment: see the code and suggest me what should i use at last if i press cancel button and want to dismiss the alert or stay on the same page @Jim

Comment: Put the last three lines of your `logoutButtonTapped:` method into the `if` statement in the delegate method.  It's not clear what else you're doing in that method, but Apple forbid manually exiting applications like that.

Comment: ok i got that, but tell me what should i write in else method how to do nothing on cancel button pressed @Jim

Comment: If you don't want to do anything, then just don't have an `else`.  You only need an `else` if you want to do something when the `if` statement evaluates to `NO`.

Comment: no but if i didn't use else then if i click cancel button then login view pops up which i don't want @ Jim

Comment: That's because you're setting your `userID` to `nil` in the wrong place.  Follow my advice and that won't happen.

Comment: i got it @ Jim i updated my code thanks for the help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37606951/show-a-button-on-getting-json-response-equal-to-a-string-like-unapproved  @ Jim this is my problem it will be great if you have any idea