# How to store data using NSUserDefaults which is fetched from URL and set them to textFields

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, nsuserdefaults

In the code below, I am getting data from an URL and storing it into `TextFields` directly. However, the data get lost when my app goes to background for a long period and I reopen it from suspended state.

Does anyone have an idea about how to fetch and store data in `NSUserDefaults`, so I don't lose it, and then show it in text fields?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://190.179.4.9:92/mybite_joomla/cron/webapi.php?task=webapi.viewProfile"]];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=UTF-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"content-type"];

    NSError *err;
    NSURLResponse *response;
    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&err];

    NSDictionary *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &err];

    for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonArray) {

        // here I am directly setting it into textfields and I need to store it first
        nameTextView.text =[jsonArray valueForKey:@"name"];   

        usernameTextView.text =[jsonArray valueForKey : @"username"];

        emailTextView.text=[jsonArray valueForKey : @"email"];

        cityTextView.text =[jsonArray valueForKey : @"city"];

        stateTextView.text =[jsonArray valueForKey : @"state"];

        countryTextView.text =[jsonArray valueForKey : @"country"];
    }
}
```

Comment: no helpful solution yet...looking for it...if anyone can help...plz answer...

Comment: Stop using `valueForKey:` unless you really need KVC.

Comment: So what should be there @ vadian

Comment: To get a single value the dedicated method is `objectForKey:`.  The repeat loop is meaningless anyway because you don't use the loop variable `dict` at all.

Comment: ya the problem is that when i use dict objectForKey:@"name" the app crashes and says - NSTaggedPointerString objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance @vadian

Comment: and still i think that is not the solution to my problem @vadian

Comment: Your types are most likely wrong. The crash log reveals that `jsonArray` is a string. The naming *NS**Dictionary** *json**Array*** is pretty confusing, too.

Comment: @vadian so what do you think what will be the solution to this, i have tried object for key also in  NSString *name =[jsonArray objectForKey:@"name"];   this way but still the same issue  data doesn't appear after i reopen the application when the user is already logged in

Comment: If the array contains only strings (or other property list compliant types) you can store the whole array directly in user defaults. But first you should resolve that type confusion. What is the print out of `jsonArray`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in jsonArray) {

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[jsonArray valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"nameString"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[jsonArray valueForKey:@"username"] forKey:@"usernameString"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[jsonArray valueForKey:@"email"] forKey:@"emailString"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[jsonArray valueForKey:@"city"] forKey:@"cityString"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[jsonArray valueForKey:@"state"] forKey:@"stateString"];

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:[jsonArray valueForKey:@"country"] forKey:@"countryString"];

    }
```

Then, in viewWillAppear :

```
    nameTextView.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"nameString"];

    usernameTextView.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"usernameString"];

    emailTextView.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"emailString"];

    cityTextView.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"cityString"];

    stateTextView.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"stateString"];

    countryTextView.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"countryString"];
```

Comment: this is like a perfect solution dude thanks a ton man, really an iOS geek ur @iOS Geek

Comment: ya dude it helped me...voted :)  but yesterday i asked a question LOGOUT related  i think this was the solution.Setting userID nil in logout button action doesn't create a problem. It will be good if u have look at that code @iOS Geek

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37658504/how-to-logout-without-setting-userid-nil  - i have voted for you answer i should have 15 reputation so other will be able to see that i have voted for your answer...in fact no one voted for my tricky question @iOS Geek

Comment: @ iOS Geek it still giving me problem dude when i try logging in on other devices in simulator and go to view profile data is not there and if i delete app from simulator on the same device on which i was logged in before and where i was able to see the view profile data, now after deleting the app when i reopen i still lose the data...

Answer (score 0):

Store:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setValue:nameTextView.text forKey:@"name"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Get:

```
NSString *value = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"name"];
```

Comment: i want fetch the data in the nameTextView.text @anhtu

Comment: @vicky You can store anything by setValue. I updated my answer.

Comment: nameTextView.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"name"];  i did this way still the text field is blank @anhtu

Comment: @vicky Updated again. Long time no use Obj-c. :). Please try

Comment: still the problem is same after storing it also it is losing the data huh... i'm fed up with this @anhtu

Comment: @vicky. First you have to store it first. Then you can get it. Maybe yo doesn't store before you get. Try to debug your code.

Comment: @vicky -  Try setting the textview text or your code in viewWillAppear. Maybe that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly get an instance of NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
```

And then you can store data:

```
NSString *name =[jsonArray valueForKey:@"name"];

[defaults setObject:name forKey:@"name"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

And fetch data:

```
NSString *storedName = [defaults stringForKey:@"name"];

nameTextView.text = storedName;
```

Comment: you should delete the first line in fetch data block it says redefinition of name @usagi_visk

Comment: I supposed you would store and fetch the data in different places. If not, that line must be deleted, you are right

Comment: still looking for solution, any help

Comment: Are the variables not being stored?

Comment: which variables u are saying